# Telerik Kendo MVC TextBox Multiline Mode

Tags: razor, textbox, kendo-asp.net-mvc, multiline, telerik-mvc

Does anyone know what properties to set to make a Kendo MVC Textbox Multiline?

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
     .Name("txtComments")
     .Value(@Model.Comments)
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
 )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want a `textarea`, I'd recommend doing it this way:

```
@Html.TextArea("textarea", "", new { @class="k-textbox", style = "width: 100%;" })
```

as their [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/styling/index) shows.  This will allow you to get the same Kendo styling, if that's what you're going for.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to remove the resize option?

Comment: If u use html.textArea then its not a Kendo control any more and just styling over it as kendo control is not acceptable

Comment: how is it not acceptable?  Kendo gave us access to the class for a reason, and that's how their own demo shows to do it.  Additionally if you view the generated javascript, most of their controls translate into bootstrap with classes on them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use with a model:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "k-textbox", style = "width: 100%;", placeholder = "Notes... Descriptions..." })
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is what you're looking for:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextArea()
```

Rather than:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBox()
```

I found this question after wondering why TextBox didn't have a "Multiline" property or something similar...  Turns out I was using the inappropriate object.

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/textarea

(Note that TextArea() may have not been available when the question was created)